# Possessive form of "which"

Tags: possessives, possessive-of-which, whose

The possessive form of `who` is `whose`. What is the equivalent possessive form of `which`?

`which` has the same purpose as `who` as a placeholder in a secondary sentence, with the difference that `who` is for people and living beings while `which` is for inanimate objects (please correct me if wrong).

Example:

> An image is read and sent to the function, **which's** output is displayed.

Here I have used an obscure word invention: `which's` in place of the word I am looking for. What is the correct word to plug in, if any? Compare with a similar `who`-sentence:

> An gift is wrapped and sent to the Peter, **whose** reaction is recorded.

---

The equivalent word in my mother tongue Danish is `hvis`:

> Et billede læses og sendes til funktionen, **hvis** output vises på skærmen.

Comment: A rock album whose cover shocked the world. There is only one possessive relative pronoun in English: whose.

Comment: I personally believe that **it doesn't exist** in English.  Workarounds include things like "A rock album, where the cover shocked the world."

Comment: Steeven, note too that you have: An image is read and sent to the function, **the output of which** is displayed.

Comment: And note that words like **wherein** are sometimes used to avoid the issue.  Example, "A novel, wherein the hero is a dog."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Whose" still works.

> An image is read and sent to the function, whose output is displayed.

Comment: @NigelJ Common knowledge doesn't really require references!

Comment: @NigelJ It isn't a website for advanced users of English. The answer is that although this is common knowledge amongst linguists of English (and any relective native speaker), the fact that people are told not to use *whose* as a pronoun for things (because of the interrogative pronoun) confuses people.

Comment: @Araucaria Agreed and accepted. Actually, there is more in this question than I realised. (Still learning, me, and just learned a new word - 'relective'.)

Comment: @NigelJ I'm always missing out etters from wors in the comments ...

Comment: @Araucaria I wasn't being rude. 'Relective' appeared to be a real word, at first, but when I investigated it later, it seems to be a misspell.

Comment: @NigelJ I wasn't being uppity, I was trying to be unny - in a frendly way;)

Comment: @Araucaria Okey dokey.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to Scotland141's perfectly valid answer, you can use *of which*, although in this case the word order is slightly different:

> An image is read and sent to the function, the output of which is displayed.

You could also maintain something closer to the original word order (sounding more formal):

> An image is read and sent to the function, of which the output is displayed.

Comment: Is `I ate a cake, of which the origin I did not know` correct? It sounds very awkward ...

Comment: @HappyFace It would be “I ate a cake, the origin of which I did not know.”